# WPF WrapPanel collapsing order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wrappanel

Does anyone know how to set order of `WrapPanel` collapse (or if it is even possible)? I want to collapse the outer `WrapPanel` before the inner one. To make it harder I have inner `WrapPanel` inside `Expander`.

```
<WrapPanel>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ExchangeButton}"  />
            <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" Header="Edition"
                      Template="{StaticResource ExpanderTemplate}">
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource AddButton}"  />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource EditButton}"  />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"  />
                </WrapPanel>
            </Expander>
</WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding or Collapsing a parent container will do the same for all its children. and their children...

This is a *good thing*.  Think about this from the other direction...if your inner container was Visible, but the outer was Hidden, there would be no way to interact with it despite its state being *visible*.  WPF takes care of all this for you and makes creating a UI that shows, hides, or collapses content easy and controllable from the highest level.